# Expo-Location not fetching device current location on Android application

Tags: react-native, expo

I am encountering an issue with expo-location in my React Native component. Even after the location permission is granted, I am unable to retrieve the device's location when generating the APK. Strangely, it works perfectly fine on Expo Go and in the iOS app.

I'm using the library as follows:

```
import * as Location from "expo-location";
// ...

React.useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
        let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
        if (status !== 'granted') {
            console.log('Permission to access location was denied');
            return;
        }
        let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
        setUserLatitude(location?.coords?.latitude);
        setUserLongitude(location?.coords?.longitude);
    })();
}, []);
```

I've ensured that the location permission is granted, and the code works on Expo Go and in the iOS app.
No specific error message, but the location is not being fetched on Android APK.
I expected the code to fetch the device's location on Android, just like it does on Expo Go and in the iOS app. However, it doesn't work as expected when generating the APK.

Environment:

1. Expo SDK version: 49.0.6
2. React Native version: 0.72.6
3. expo-locationversion: 16.1.0

Comment: Can you share your plugins array from app.json?

Comment: "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-location",
        {
          "locationAlwaysAndWhenInUsePermission": "App needs location for xyz purpose"
        }
      ],
    ],

Comment: Can you try adding the key for android?

isAndroidBackgroundLocationEnabled: true

Comment: Yes it is still the same